# enscroll plugin doesnot work with display:none element

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have three hidden div's where I'm using ensroll plug in to style scroll bars. everything works fine but when the element is hidden after opening once scrollbars float around.

below is the jsfiddle link for the code. click on all brands and fashion and hide both to as u hover over all brands the scroll bar will appear around.

------JS------

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.init-hidden').hide();

    $('#brandgroupoptions-all').enscroll({
        showOnHover: true,
        verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
        verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
    });

    $('#brandgroupoptions-fashion').enscroll({
        showOnHover: true,
        verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
        verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
    });

    $('#brandgroupoptions-beauty').enscroll({
        showOnHover: true,
        verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
        verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
    });

    $('#brandgroupopen-fashion').click(function () {
        $('#brandgroupoptions-fashion').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#brandgroupopen-all').click(function () {
        $('#brandgroupoptions-all').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#brandgroupopen-beauty').click(function () {
        $('#brandgroupoptions-beauty').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soniayastays/n2BAS/

please advice.

Thanks

Comment: forget abuot enscroll plugin or fix it to hide or disable instance if element is hidden

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with the enscroll plugin. Please watch the following issue if you're still waiting for a resolution: https://github.com/jstoudt/enscroll/issues/21